# C: Getting garbage characters when printing an array declared in shared memory

Tags: c, arrays, unix, shared-memory

I'm trying to declare an array of string into shared memory.
server.c creates the shared memory and client.c fills the array "tab" and print it.And it's working just fine in the client side.
but I get garbage characters when running the server.c !

Any help would be appreciated!

**server.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct People
{
  char *tab[5];

  } Person;
  int i;

  int main()
{   
system("clear");
Person aaron;
Person *p_aaron;
int id;
int key = 12345;

p_aaron = &aaron;

if ((id = shmget(key,1000, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
{
    perror("SHMGET");
    exit(1);
}
printf("server: size: %d \n", sizeof(aaron));

if((p_aaron = shmat(id, NULL, 0)) == (Person *) -1)
{
    perror("SHMAT");
    exit(1);
}

 for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
   printf("server tab: %s \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct People
{
char *tab[5];

} Person;
int test;
int i;

int main()
{   

system("clear");

Person aaron;
Person *p_aaron;
int id;
int key = 12345;

p_aaron = &aaron;

id = shmget(key,1000, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
p_aaron = shmat(id, NULL, 0);

    p_aaron->tab[0]="abnb";
    p_aaron->tab[1]="b";
    p_aaron->tab[2]="c";
    p_aaron->tab[3]="d";
    p_aaron->tab[4]="e";

 for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
   printf("client tab: %s \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```

**server.c output**

```
server tab: � 
server tab: � 
server tab: � 
server tab: � 
server tab: �
```

**client.c output**

```
client tab: abnb 
client tab: b 
client tab: c 
client tab: d 
client tab: e
```

Comment: Your "array of string" is an array of *pointers*, and they don't mean, nor refer to, the same data in the *server* process as they do in the *client* process.

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Comment: On the server side you have `printf("server tab: %c \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);` with the incorrect `%c` format specifier. On the client side you have `printf("client tab: %s \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);` Is the problem just a typo?

Comment: The simplest solution is to declare an array of strings `char tab[5][MAXLEN]` and make it shared (`MAXLEN` is the length of the longest element + 1).

Comment: @WeatherVane no no , I've already tried that.
I'm getting garbage characters too.

Comment: Well at least correct the code posted to use `%s` as is proper for a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's working just fine with integer

Comment: The `%c` format in `printf("server tab: %c \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);` is not an integer. It is a character. Until you correct that to `%s`, you won't know if the code is working after fixing other problems.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean I already changed `printf("server tab: %c \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);` to `printf("server tab: %d \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);`

Comment: For shared memory to work, the data must all be in shared memory.  If you store pointers directly in the shared memory, you must make sure that both the client and server load the shared memory at the same address — if they don't, the pointers will be meaningless to one or the other.  Your string literals are not in shared memory — you have major problems as a result.  The diagnosis by [DYZ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) in their [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41539386) is spot on.  The prescription to remedy the diagnosis is a little scanty.

Comment: One portable way to store 'pointers' is to record (byte) offsets relative to the start of the shared memory when you need to store a pointer.  Variations on the theme work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on @DYZ answer
As DYZ suggested your string literals are not visible to the server. Try using an array as below:

common.h

```
#ifndef _COMMON_H_
#define _COMMON_H_

#define MAX_CHAR    10
typedef struct People
{
char tab[5][MAX_CHAR];

} Person;

#endif /* _COMMON_H_ */
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "common.h"

int test;
int i;

int main()
{

    Person aaron;
    Person *p_aaron;
    int id;
    int key = 12345;

    p_aaron = &aaron;

    id = shmget(key,1000, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    p_aaron = shmat(id, NULL, 0);

    snprintf(p_aaron->tab[0],MAX_CHAR,"%s","abnb");
    snprintf(p_aaron->tab[1],MAX_CHAR,"%s","bcde");
    snprintf(p_aaron->tab[2],MAX_CHAR,"%s","c");
    snprintf(p_aaron->tab[3],MAX_CHAR,"%s","d");
    snprintf(p_aaron->tab[4],MAX_CHAR,"%s","e");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("client tab: %s \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int i;

int main()
{
    system("clear");
    Person aaron;
    Person *p_aaron;
    int id;
    int key = 12345;

    p_aaron = &aaron;

    if ((id = shmget(key,1000, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("SHMGET");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("server: size: %lu \n", sizeof(aaron));

    if((p_aaron = shmat(id, NULL, 0)) == (Person *) -1)
    {
        perror("SHMAT");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("server tab: %s \n", p_aaron->tab[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The literal strings that you use to initialize the pointers are not in the shared memory and not visible to the server. The simplest solution is to declare an array of strings `char tab[5][MAXLEN]` and make it shared (MAXLEN is the length of the longest element + 1).

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you,I misunderstood your answer !